# Darboux integral on interval where the integrand is not defined on a point

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f(x) = x, x \in [0,2]\setminus \{1\}$.

Question: is a Darboux integral $$I = \int_0^2 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$$ well defined and equal $I = 2$?

Comment: You can separately consider the integrals on [0,1) and (1,2]

Comment: @FrozerClark An answer showing how to do that would be cool.

Comment: Did your source define integral on non-closed intervals?
If no, then I don't think the Darboux integral is well defined in this context.

Comment: If your source have defined integral on non-closed intervals, then you can take some increasing closed sub-interval $[0,a_n]$ of [0,1) with $0\leq a_1\leq...\leq a_n\leq...$ and $a_n\to 1$. 
We can define $\int_0^1f(x)dx:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{a_n}f(x)dx$ if you can show that the limits exist and they the same for any increasing sequence $a_n\to1$.